# Quantum Machine Learning-qiskit: Ramdon accuracy using VQC and Iris dataset

Tags: python, random-seed, qiskit

I have a problem building a cirquit using qiskit.machine_learning, for iris classification.  I've been using the same seed in QuantumInstance creation (seed_simulator, seed_transpiler and random_state) but I get different accuracy when running it several times. In Aqua library (from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQC) I solved it adding aqua_globals.random_seed. In machine learning (from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms import VQC) we have the equivalent: algorithm_globals.random_seed. But the problem continues.

[image: First Execution]

[image: Second Execution]

[image: Seed is taking into account in the configuration of the different simulators]

In different tests, I found the randomness using PCA or StandarScaler and MinMaxScaler, but after different tests it happened again in all scenarios.

I think the seed is not taking into account during the training and probably it could probably be a bug.

Someone else has found this issue?

Comment: please read the tag contents: [tag:qml] is different to *Quantum Machine Learning*

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, I've read a lot of papers and articles referencing to quantum machine learning as qml too. https://towardsdatascience.com/quantum-machine-learning-its-time-to-start-now-1f5a1ee9bc31. https://www.quantummachinelearning.org/. https://science.sciencemag.org/content/new-algorithm-quantum-machine-learning-qml. So for that reason, I added as tag. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it works inicializing the qubits and save_statevector and probabilities:

```
ans.initialize([1/np.sqrt(2), -1/np.sqrt(2)], 0)
ans.initialize([1/np.sqrt(2), -1/np.sqrt(2)], 1)
vqc.circuit.save_state()
vqc.circuit.save_probabilities()
vqc.circuit.save_statevector()
```

Regards!